# Drag an HTML box and make another box follow it with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create something like drag a box (Hello World) to any location, and the second box (Follow World) will follow slowly.

In the code below, the drag box is fine, but the follow box will not follow properly. Also, the drag box cannot drop.

```js
function startDrag(e) {
  // determine event object
  if (!e) {
    var e = window.event;
  }

  // IE uses srcElement, others use target
  var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

  if (targ.className != 'dragme') {
    return
  };
  // calculate event X, Y coordinates
  offsetX = e.clientX;
  offsetY = e.clientY;

  // assign default values for top and left properties
  if (!targ.style.left) {
    targ.style.left = '0px'
  };
  if (!targ.style.top) {
    targ.style.top = '0px'
  };

  // calculate integer values for top and left 
  // properties
  coordX = parseInt(targ.style.left);
  coordY = parseInt(targ.style.top);
  drag = true;

  // move div element
  document.onmousemove = dragDiv;
  return false;
}

function dragDiv(e) {
  if (!drag) {
    return
  };
  if (!e) {
    var e = window.event
  };
  var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;
  // move div element
  targ.style.left = coordX + e.clientX - offsetX + 'px';
  targ.style.top = coordY + e.clientY - offsetY + 'px';
  return false;
}

function stopDrag() {
  timer();
  drag = false;
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.onmousedown = startDrag;
  document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
}

function disp() {
  var step = 1;
  var y = document.getElementById('followme').offsetTop;
  var x = document.getElementById('followme').offsetLeft;
  var ty = document.getElementById('draggable').offsetTop;
  var ty = document.getElementById('draggable').offsetLeft;

  if (y < ty) {
    y = y + step;
    document.getElementById('followme').style.top = y + "px"; // vertical movment
  } else {
    if (x < tx) {
      x = x + step;
      document.getElementById('followme').style.left = x + "px"; // horizontal movment
    }
  }
}

function timer() {
  disp();
  var y = document.getElementById('followme').offsetTop;
  var x = document.getElementById('followme').offsetLeft;
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "X: " + tx + " Y : " + ty
  my_time = setTimeout('timer()', 10);
}
```

```css
.dragme {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: move;
}
.followme {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
}
#draggable {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#followme {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Drag and drop</title>


</head>

<body>
  <div id='msg'></div>
  <div id="draggable" class="dragme">"Hello World!"</div>
  <div id="followme" class="followme">"Follow World!"</div>
```

Comment: Did you see my answer? You can accept mine instead if you think it's better.

Comment: Is the follow world stalking new developers saying "Hello World"?

Comment: My snippet is inspired by the movie titled *It Follows*. Watch it and you'll understand everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix yours `disp` and `timer` functions to this:

```
function disp()
{
    var step = 1;

    // in dragDiv() you modifying style.left/style.top properties, not offsetTop/offsetLeft
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('followme').style.left) || 0;
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById('followme').style.top) || 0;

    var tx = parseInt(document.getElementById('draggable').style.left) || 0;
    var ty = parseInt(document.getElementById('draggable').style.top) || 0;

    // properly calculate offset
    var dx = ((dx = tx - x) == 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(dx) / dx;
    var dy = ((dy = ty - y) == 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(dy) / dy;

    document.getElementById('followme').style.left = (x + dx * step) + "px"; // horisontal movment
    document.getElementById('followme').style.top  = (y + dy * step) + "px"; // vertical movment
}

function timer()
{
    disp();
    var y=document.getElementById('followme').offsetTop;
    var x=document.getElementById('followme').offsetLeft;
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="X: " + x + " Y : " + y; // typo was here

    my_time = setTimeout(function () {
      clearTimeout(my_time); // need to clear timeout or it'll be adding each time 'Hello world' clicked
      timer();
    },10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following snippet, the pink box is draggable and the blue box follows it around. You can change `pixelsPerSecond` to adjust the speed of movement.

```js
function message(s) {
  document.getElementById('messageContainer').innerHTML = s;
}

window.onload = function () {
  var pixelsPerSecond = 80,
      drag = document.getElementById('drag'),
      follow = document.getElementById('follow'),
      wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper'),
      messageContainer = document.getElementById('messageContainer'),
      leftMax,
      topMax;
  function setBoundaries() {
    leftMax = wrapper.offsetWidth - drag.offsetWidth;
    topMax = wrapper.offsetHeight - drag.offsetHeight;
    drag.style.left = Math.min(drag.offsetLeft, leftMax) + 'px';
    drag.style.top = Math.min(drag.offsetTop, topMax) + 'px';
  }
  setBoundaries();
  window.onresize = setBoundaries;
  [drag, follow, messageContainer].forEach(function (element) {
    element.className += ' unselectable';
    element.ondragstart = element.onselectstart = function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    };
  });
  var start = Date.now();
  drag.onmousedown = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var x0 = event.pageX || event.clientX,
        y0 = event.pageY || event.clientY,
        left0 = drag.offsetLeft,
        top0 = drag.offsetTop;
    window.onmousemove = function (event) {
      var x = event.pageX || event.clientX,
          y = event.pageY || event.clientY;
      drag.style.left = Math.max(0, Math.min(left0 + x - x0, leftMax)) + 'px';
      drag.style.top = Math.max(0, Math.min(top0 + y - y0, topMax)) + 'px';
    };
    window.onmouseup = function () {
      window.onmousemove = window.onmouseup = undefined;
    };
  };
  follow.x = follow.offsetLeft;
  follow.y = follow.offsetTop;
  function update() {
    var elapsed = Date.now() - start;
    if (elapsed === 0) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
      return;
    }
    var x1 = drag.offsetLeft,
        y1 = drag.offsetTop + (drag.offsetTop + drag.offsetHeight <= topMax ?
              drag.offsetHeight : -drag.offsetHeight),
        x0 = follow.x,
        y0 = follow.y,
        dx = x1 - x0,
        dy = y1 - y0,
        distance = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy),
        angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx),
        dd = Math.min(distance, pixelsPerSecond * elapsed / 1000);
    message('x: ' + x1 + ', y: ' + y1);
    follow.x += Math.cos(angle) * dd;
    follow.style.left = follow.x + 'px';
    follow.y += Math.sin(angle) * dd;
    follow.style.top = follow.y + 'px';
    start = Date.now();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.unselectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-drag: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
#messageContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  top: 50px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: default;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
}
.label {
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#drag {
  left: 100px;
  top: 120px;
  background: #f0dddb;
  border: 2px solid #deb7bb;
  cursor: move;
}
#follow {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ddebf3;
  border: 2px solid #bfd5e1;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="messageContainer"></div>

<div class="box" id="follow"> <div class="label">it follows</div> </div>

<div class="box" id="drag"> <div class="label">drag me</div> </div>
```